# snmpget timeouts when using unix socket address

Tags: snmp, unix-socket, snmpd

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I've changed `snmpd.conf` for listening to unix socket instead of its default udp port 161, but `snmpget` fails with Timeout error.

Before changing the config file this was working:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public localhost SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0
```

with an output like this:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = Timeticks: (1453) 0:00:14.53
```

Then I changed `agentAddress` in the config file like below:

```
agentAddress unix:/tmp/snmp/agent.sock
```

And restarted snmpd service. Now when I use `snmpget` like this:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public unix:/tmp/snmp/agent.sock SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0
```

It errors:

```
Timeout: No Response from unix:/tmp/snmp/agent.sock.
```

In [snmpd man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/snmpd) it said that listening address could be changed to unix socket but it seems not working.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz Why? That has nothing to do with the question. If you have a question about the performance impact of UNIX Sockets (as compared to some other thing, in some particular circumstance) then you should ask a new question, clearly and with all required detail.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit your right, but I have an [question about this clearly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56822296/1539100) and does get any satisfiable answer  about that, so I hope someone answer this in another related question :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit anyway I deleted my comment :)

Comment: Don't spam other people's questions to get answers to your own, unrelated questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the -x option, as indicated in the nam page you sited.